# How do I save array of bytes as array in NEST

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have a simple POCO object with following definition

```
class MyClass 
{
   public byte[] Assortment {get;set;}
}
```

And I want to save it as `[1,2,3]` in elasticsearch. But when I simply create an object of that type and insert it into index I just get some binary encoded value. Sample code:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(elasticSettings.NodeUri)).DefaultIndex(elasticSettings.Index);
var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
MyClass[] requests = { new MyClass {Assortment = new byte[] {1,3,40,2,9,4,7,5,8,47,45,46,38,39,6} }};
var bulkResponse = await elasticClient.IndexManyAsync(requests, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

If I manually create an index and set array type I get following errors when saving:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error while processing bulk request: Invalid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /_bulk
# Invalid Bulk items:
  operation[0]: index returned 400 _index: blockchain _type: elasticrequest _id: eqa04WUByNd1edqilegT _version: 0 error: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to parse [assortment]" CausedBy:
Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "For input string: "AQMoAgkEBwUILy0uJicG""
  operation[1]: index returned 400 _index: blockchain _type: elasticrequest _id: e6a04WUByNd1edqilegT _version: 0 error: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to parse [assortment]" CausedBy:
Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "For input string: "AQMoAgkEBwUILy0uJicG""
  operation[2]: index returned 400 _index: blockchain _type: elasticrequest _id: fKa04WUByNd1edqilegT _version: 0 error: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to parse [assortment]" CausedBy:
Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "For input string: "AQMoAgkEBwUILy0uJicG""
```

I don't want to binary encode the value, I just want to create an array of values.

I tried Text/Number/Object attributes, but they don't work.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example for `GetRequests()`. Also, could you show the mapping for the index in question?

Comment: @RussCam of course, see edit.